# Deploying charm installer from local repository

Tags: juju, maas, repository, openstack, cloud

I am using openstack charm bundle to install openstack on a MAAS setup. My requirement is that the services get installed from a local repository. [ Not to be confused with local charms]

For example,  source: cloud:trusty-kilo is configured in the charm bundle. I want this to point to a local repository. [ As of now , i only want to clone the public repository and maintain it locally. Later i would want to make changes to the openstack code and update this repository.]

```
  ceph:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '750'
      gui-y: '500'
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-38
    num_units: 3
    options:
      fsid: 5a791d94-980b-11e4-b6f6-3c970e8b1cf7
      monitor-secret: AQAi5a9UeJXUExAA+By9u+GPhl8/XiUQ4nwI3A==
      osd-devices: /dev/sdb
      osd-reformat: 'yes'
      source: cloud:trusty-kilo
```

Answer (score 1):

The ceph charm's "source" config option can be used in a number of ways.  As long as the local repo is also served and accessible by remote systems (such as http://), the source config option can be used.

Here is an excerpt from the config.yaml file in the charm:

```
  source:
    type: string
    default:
    description: |
      Optional configuration to support use of additional sources such as:

        - ppa:myteam/ppa
        - cloud:trusty-proposed/kilo
        - http://my.archive.com/ubuntu main

      The last option should be used in conjunction with the key configuration
      option.

      Note that a minimum ceph version of 0.48.2 is required for use with this
      charm which is NOT provided by the packages in the main Ubuntu archive
      for precise but is provided in the Ubuntu cloud archive.
```

It may also be helpful to review the following docstring from the underlying code which acts on the source value:

```
Add a package source to this system.

@param source: a URL or sources.list entry, as supported by
add-apt-repository(1). Examples::

ppa:charmers/example
deb https://stub:key@private.example.com/ubuntu trusty main

In addition:
'proposed:' may be used to enable the standard 'proposed'
pocket for the release.
'cloud:' may be used to activate official cloud archive pockets,
such as 'cloud:icehouse'
'distro' may be used as a noop

@param key: A key to be added to the system's APT keyring and used
to verify the signatures on packages. Ideally, this should be an
ASCII format GPG public key including the block headers. A GPG key
id may also be used, but be aware that only insecure protocols are
available to retrieve the actual public key from a public keyserver
placing your Juju environment at risk. ppa and cloud archive keys
are securely added automtically, so sould not be provided.
```